# Ansible Cisco output creating empty file

Tags: linux, ansible, cisco

Only output from the first command is written to the file.

How do I make it write output from all of the commands to the file?

```
---

- name: run show commands
  hosts: nexus1
  gather_facts: False


  tasks:
  - name: run show commands on nexus
    nxos_command:
      commands:
        - show hostname
        - show ip route
        - show interface
        - show ip interface vrf all 
        - show hsrp
    register: output

  - name: Copy to server
    copy:
      content: "{{ output.stdout[0] }}"
      dest: "/home/CiscoOutPut/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only *asking* for output from the first command. `output.stdout` is a list, one item for the output of each command. When ask for `output.stdout[0]`, you're asking for only the first result.

If you want to write the output of all commands to a file, then something like:

```
  - name: Copy to server
    copy:
      content: "{{ '\n'.join(output.stdout) }}"
      dest: "/home/CiscoOutPut/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```

Comment: This also works: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/47973